# How make Vue Multiselect accessible to screen reader?

Tags: vue.js

I recently replaced a dropdown with Vue Multiselect.
I intend to make the multiselect options accessible.

The issue:
When I press tab the focus does come on the multiselect and read out the default option.
But, when I press the down arrow key to scroll through the options, the screen reader fails to read them out.

I have tried invoking a fuction to programatically set focus on the child options but that didn't quite seem to completely work,

The following sets focus on the default, but I don't know how to set focus on the child options,

```
this.$refs.managermultiselect.$el.focus()
```

Following is the HTML,

```
<multiselect v-model="value"
    aria-autocomplete="list"
    aria-activedescendant=""
    ref="managermultiselect"
    label="LastName"
    @keydown.native="keymonitor"
    :options="manageroptions"
    :multiple="true"
    :custom-label="customLabel">
</multiselect>
```

Comment: Looks like you might need to manually handle the events. can you provide a minimal reprodusable example to play with?

Comment: Here is a fiddle link, https://jsfiddle.net/0q1jz9nw/1/   Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you pleas add why you use a `multiselect` element (which does not exist in HTML 5.2) instead of [`select` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-select-element) with a `multiple` attribute? Using existing elements is always better for accessibility.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe
Its more for aesthtic reasons.  I did have a select earlier with the multiple attribute as you mentioned, but I couldn't seem to make it work through 'select' as well.